# Mosaic view RTSP Streaming on RPI using gstreamer gearated from VLC

Tags: raspberry-pi, rtsp, gstreamer, mosaic

I am working on developing an application to get a mosaic view of a player on RPI(raspberry pi with raspbeain OS) which can play RTSP Streaming generated from vlc player from my x86 machine with Ubuntu.

I have installed Gstremaer-1.0 and currently able to play one view of RTSP steaming (successfully)in full screen using this command generated by vlc please refer 1st screen shot.
[image: Sucesfuly able to play one screen rtsp streaming on rpi]

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.65:8554/test ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! autovideosink`

But when i go for four screen mosaic view using below command (got this command after some googling around),

`gst-launch-1.0 -vvv videomixer name=mix  rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.65:8554/test1 ! 'video/x-h264,framerate=(fraction)50/1,width=640,height=480' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! mix. rtspsrc location=192.168.1.65:8554/test1 ! 'video/x-h264,framerate=(fraction)50/1,width=640,height=480' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! mix.rtspsrc location=192.168.1.65:8554/test1 ! 'video/x-h264,framerate=(fraction)50/1,width=640,height=480' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! mix.rtspsrc location=192.168.1.65:8554/test1 ! 'video/x-h264,framerate=(fraction)50/1,width=640,height=480' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! mix.`

it gives me an error attached with below screenshot

so what is there that i am missing here or is there another way to do this ?

Any help on this topic would be appreciable.
Thank You !
[image: Mosaic view RTSP Error log using gstreamer]

Answer (score -1):

there is no videosink, try adding autovideosink:

gst-launch-1.0 -vvv videomixer name=mix autovideosink rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.65:8554/test1 ! 'video/x-h264,framerate=(fraction)50/1,width=640,height=480' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! mix. rtspsrc location=192.168.1.65:8554/test1 ! 'video/x-h264,framerate=(fraction)50/1,width=640,height=480' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! mix.rtspsrc location=192.168.1.65:8554/test1 ! 'video/x-h264,framerate=(fraction)50/1,width=640,height=480' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! mix.rtspsrc location=192.168.1.65:8554/test1 ! 'video/x-h264,framerate=(fraction)50/1,width=640,height=480' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! mix.